# Cannot update due a Claro Colombia ISP issue

Tags: internet

I have a problem updating because my ISP, Claro Colombia, uses a public IP range as a private network (5.x.x.x), and mirrordirector.raspbian.org (5.153.225.207) uses this ip range.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That sounds a bit odd - the Class A private address range is `10.x.x.x` NOT `5.x.x.x` - so if you ping `5.153.225.207` or try to browse it you do not get a ftp like listing with at least a `raspbian` sub-directory?

Comment: @SlySven They're weird.

Comment: @SlySven The ISP I mean.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is add/replace the repositories used by what I'm guessing is `apt-get`.

The file you need to modify is `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Open it up with your favorite editor and

1. You could completely replace the default `deb` entries (just comment them out to be safe)
2. Add the mirrors as new entries. I got them from [here](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors), hand-picked since some of the ones in the list are dead.

Sample config (change yours accordingly based on your Raspbian version)

```
#------------------------DEFAULT DEB ENTRIES------------------------
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

#Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
#--------------------------END OF DEFAULTS--------------------------


# ADDITIONAL ENTRIES, YOU CAN COPY THESE AND PASTE TO YOUR CONFIG FILE
# TAKE NOTE I AM USING RASPBIAN JESSIE, CHANGE YOURS ACCORDINGLY

#EUROPE
deb http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://raspbian.insideelectronics.co.uk/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://raspbian.lag.re/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi

#NORTH AMERICA
deb http://mirror.nexcess.net/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://mirror.glennmcgurrin.com/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

#SOUTH AMERICA
deb http://raspbian.ufms.br/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://raspbian.c3sl.ufpr.br/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

#ASIA
deb http://mirror.rise.ph/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```